# Django : Template translation not working

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

My web application's default language code is Korean.

I'd like to translate it into English when client's `Accept-language` is `en-us`.

I prefer to use **template translation**, not the python code or `i18n_urlpatterns`.

Here is my code.

---

***Django version***

```
    1.7.7
```

---

***settings.py***

```
    ...

    def ABS_PATH(*args):
        return os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, *args)    

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko'
    ugettext = lambda s: s
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', ugettext('English')),
        ('ko', ugettext('Korean')),
    )
    LOCALE_PATHS = (
        ABS_PATH('locale'),     # /var/www/mysite.com/locale
    )
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = True

    ...

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        ...
    )

    # `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` have `django.core.context_processors.i18n` as default.
```

---

***views.py***

```
    def home(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

***index.html***

```
    {% load i18n %}
    ...
    {% trans "Hello" %}
    ...
```

---

***Make message file on shell***

`$ django-admin.py makemessages -l en`

---

***Edit message file*** *`/var/www/mysite.com/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`*

```
    #: .../index.html:14
    msgid "Hello"
    msgstr "안녕"
```

---

***Compile message file on shell***

`$ django-admin.py compilemessages`

*`Check file at /var/www/mysite.com/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo`*

---

***Restart test server***

`$ manage.py runserver`

---

***Check through browser***

`Accept-language : en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6`

```
    Expectation : 안녕

    Result : Hello
```

---

What should I do to show English template when client browser's `Accept-language` header is `en-us` ?

Comment: I changed language at chrome browser's setting and checked 'Accept-language' through django_debug_toolbar's header panel.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was my mistake. How stupid I am ..

`ABS_PATH('locale')` returned `/var/www/mysite.com/mysite/locale`

Changing `ABS_PATH('locale')` into `/var/www/mysite.com/locale` solved problem

I hope above steps could be helpful for others.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem. I hadn't realised that LOCALE_PATHS had to be set in settings.py for translation to work (the dev server doesn't print any warnings about missing path!)